# LINQ expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I've read in a book on LINQ that there is possibility to build expression trees for queries manually (using members of Expression class). It's written there that it may require for some accurate query tuning, that usual query operators can't perform. I can't imagine a situation of this kind, can anyone give me some example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, one does this when the entity or collection types are not known at compile time, or when the query cannot be hard-coded (e.g., to allow for user-provided group/sort/filter criteria).  This can be cumbersome, hence the emergence of libraries like Dynamic LINQ which allow you to side-step this process and dynamically construct your query criteria as text.  Those libraries will then parse your criteria and do the expression tree construction themselves, similarly to how you would have built it manually using the `Expression` APIs.

Beyond those, I can only think of one additional case when it is *necessary* to build a tree manually: when you have a reference to an `Expression<TDelegate>`, and you want to include it as a nested expression within another expression tree.  Even if everything is statically typed, you can't do this directly in C# with a lambda expression because you can't `Invoke` the nested expression (you could invoke a `TDelegate`, but not an `Expression<TDelegate>`).  Thus, you must build up the tree manually.  See [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344296/nested-lambda-expressions/26365310#26365310) for an example.

Comment: A-ha! So it can be used instead of dynamic LINQ? And is it possible to construct an expression representing a group by operator generating a single SQL query? Cause at the moment my usage of a simple group by leads to multiple queries, I don't know why.

Comment: It's not that you can use these *instead of* something like Dynamic LINQ; this is how Dynamic LINQ works under the covers.  You build expression trees manually when you can't emit them statically as C# expressions.  As for the SQL generated, that depends on the LINQ `IQueryable` provider you are using--whether it's the Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, or something else.  That library will determine how to map a LINQ expression tree to SQL.  I'm not familiar enough with any of those to tell you why your grouping expression leads to multiple queries.

Comment: Added a blurb about Dynamic LINQ in hopes of clearing things up.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know.